# Dynamic Where in linq MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic

I am trying to filter a model with two dropdown in an MVC project

```
var model = (from x in db.TABLE....
            join y in db.TABLE...).Where(where)...
```

my logic is

```
            String where = string.Empty;

            if (search.anno != null)
                where = " ANNO = " + search.anno ;

            if (search.Cliente != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
                {
                    where += " And CODICE_CLIENTE = '" + search.Cliente + "'";                 }
                else
                {
                    where = " CODICE_CLIENTE = '" + search.Cliente + "'";
                }
            }
```

i get an error: System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: Character literal must contain exactly one character

i get that in     where += " And CODICE_CLIENTE = '" + search.Cliente + "'";

i saw that the Apex at the end is '"

how can solve

Comment: Do you get the error if search.anno is not null?

Comment: yes ! I saw in debug ANNO = 2015 And CODICE_CLIENTE = '00106'" and i get that error

Comment: if only Anno is filtered the controller works ...but with the customer filter not works

Comment: I think you have to use double equals for the expressions: CODICE_CLIENTE == ....

Comment: could you suggest how? i need some escape char ?

Comment: Also, you need to double quote the string, not single quote: CODICE_CLIENTE == \"" + search.Cliente + "\""

Comment: thanks so much !:)

Comment: Last question: i want add few checkbox and how can i set the where clause ? Should I write like property IN ('A','B','C') ? Like in T-SQL right ?

Comment: That's a different issue and will need more info to answer

Comment: if (search.linea != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
                {
                    List<string> lineaSelezionate = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in search.linea)
                    {
                        lineaSelezionate.Add(item);
                    }
                    where += " And lineaSelezionate.Contains(LINEA) ";
                }
                else
                {
                    where = "lineaSelezionate.Contains(i.LINEA) ";
                }
            }

Comment: That i wrote is what i had if i use linq and not dynamic string  !

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633066/query-data-using-contains-keyword-in-dynamic-linq-in-c-sharp

Comment: tks again man !!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use double equals for the expression and double quotes for the strings 
                String where = string.Empty;

```
            if (search.anno != null)
                where = " ANNO == " + search.anno ;

            if (search.Cliente != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
                {
                    where += " And CODICE_CLIENTE == \"" + search.Cliente + "\"";                 }
                else
                {
                    where = " CODICE_CLIENTE == \"" + search.Cliente + "\"";
                }
            }
```

**Note** that this is prone to SQL injection and should be avoided, you should use parameters, something like this:

```
var model = (from x in db.TABLE.... join y in db.TABLE...).Where(whereString, params)...
```

Comment: An answer that allows [SQL Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) I don't approve of.

Comment: Right ! Like SQL ! Could you show me how with the example above ?

Answer (score 0):

This example translated into Linq without allowing [Sql Injection Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
        String where = string.Empty;

        if (search.anno != null)
            where = " ANNO = " + search.anno ;

        if (search.Cliente != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
            {
                where += " And CODICE_CLIENTE = '" + search.Cliente + "'";                 }
            else
            {
                where = " CODICE_CLIENTE = '" + search.Cliente + "'";
            }
        }
```

Would look like:

```
IQueryable<x> query = (from x in db.TABLE....
  join y in db.TABLE...);


if (search.anno != null)
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.ANNO == search.anno);
}   

if (search.Cliente != null)
{
  query = query.WHere(x => x.CODICE_CLIENTE == search.Cliente);
}

var model = query.ToList();  // or await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Ok I Know this kind of logic! But Im tryng to use dynamic linq to improve that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201615/improve-pivot-linq-to-entities

Comment: at this point select new
                        {
                            ANNO = ordine.Anno,
                            LINEA = linea,
                            MESE = ordine.Datord.Value.Month,
                            CODICE_CLIENTE = ordine.Codcli,
                            IMPORTO = rigaOrdine.Import
                        }).Where(where)

Comment: Nobody answer  and so i tried with dynamic linq : filtering the Iqueryable object i improved about 60% time execution

Answer (score 0):

I solved so ...
 String where = string.Empty;
        object[] parameters = null;

```
    if (search.anno != null)
        where = " ANNO = @0 ";
      parameters = new object[] { search.anno };

    if (search.Cliente != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
        {
            where += " && CODICE_CLIENTE = @1";
            parameters = new object[] { search.anno, search.Cliente };
        }
        else
        {
            where = " CODICE_CLIENTE = @0";
            parameters = new object[] { search.Cliente };
        }
    }

    if (search.linea != null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
        {
            where += " && LINEA.Contains(@2) ";
            parameters = new object[] { search.anno, search.Cliente, search.linea };
        }
        else
        {
            where = " LINEA.Contains(@0) ";
            parameters = new object[] { search.linea };
        }
    }
```

but the problem is with LINEA property (anonimous type): it is string and i cant use Contains(@p) tanks again for all the replay and help you provided