# Contains Dynamic where linq

Tags: c#, linq

This problem follow a preceding post (
[Dynamic Where in linq MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280938/dynamic-where-in-linq-mvc/43281659#43281659))

```
if (search.anno != null)
    where = " ANNO = @0 ";
  parameters = new object[] { search.anno };

if (search.Cliente != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
    {
        where += " && CODICE_CLIENTE = @1";
        parameters = new object[] { search.anno, search.Cliente };
    }
    else
    {
        where = " CODICE_CLIENTE = @0";
        parameters = new object[] { search.Cliente };
    }
}

if (search.linea != null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
    {
        where += " && LINEA.Contains(@2) ";
        parameters = new object[] { search.anno, search.Cliente, search.linea };
    }
    else
    {
        where = " LINEA.Contains(@0) ";
        parameters = new object[] { search.linea };
    }
}
```

I cant use `LINEA.Contains` because in my model `LINEA` is `anonimous type` string
How can solve the filter for LINEA?

Comment: What are you trying to express by something like `LINEA.Contains({ search.anno, search.Cliente, search.linea }) `?

Comment: I try to add parameters to Where(myStringWhere,parameters). Firts two filter works but the last not works

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/43201615/  here is my logic

Comment: I get an error say string LINEA not has Contains method. Linea is an anonimous property that i temporary use in my model.

Comment: I guess what I trying to ask is: what exactly should `LINEA.Contains(@2)` do? What do you expect `LINEA` to contain? It's just that I wonder if this `Contains` makes sense. I think you want to test if a list of strings contains `LINEA`.

Comment: I would test if one or more of 3 check boxes is selected. LINEA is Product lines. My search model contains a property string[] linea. So yes, i would test if one or more of value in checkbox is contained in LINEA. what i wrong?

Comment: If it is a single option as radiobutton is easy but in that case there are multiple select.