# In or Contains query using System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

**Background:** I would like to use System.Linq.Dynamic library to post In/Contains query to MS SQL

Please note I am trying to use System.Linq.Dynamic in generic function so that I could apply customer filter to any class having CustomerId(integer) property. Also CustomerId property could be nullable

All SO posts redirects me to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633066/query-data-using-contains-keyword-in-dynamic-linq-in-c-sharp). After implementing the same I keep getting this exception: "No generic method 'Contains' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic."

And now this is how **my code looks like**:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyCustomerFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> collection, int[] customerIds)
{
    return collection.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.CustomerId)", customerIds);
}


public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{    
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId))]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Could you please guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that this only works when `T is int`, making the generic function rather non-generic?

Comment: Well that's not true. It would work with any class having customer id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `MyUser.CustomerId` property is nullable - you should pass nullable int array as `customerIds` in this case. For example:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyCustomerFilter<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> collection, 
    int?[] customerIds) { // < - note here
        return collection.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.CustomerId)", customerIds);
}
```

or convert passed array to array of nullable ints:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyCustomerFilter<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> collection, 
    int[] customerIds) {
        return collection.Where("@0.Contains(outerIt.CustomerId)",
             customerIds.Cast<int?>()); // <- note here
}
```

Alternatives proposed by Ivan Stoev in comments (with them `customerIds` array can be regular `int[]` array, no need for it to be array of nullables):

```
"@0.Contains(outerIt.CustomerId.Value)"
```

And this one will work in both cases (whether `CustomerId` is nullable or not):

```
"@0.Contains(Int32(outerIt.CustomerId))"
```

Comment: Or convert property to `int` - `"@0.Contains(outerIt.CustomerId.Value)"` or `"@0.Contains(int(outerIt.CustomerId))"`

Comment: @IvanStoev last proposal ("@0.Contains(int(outerIt.CustomerId))") seems to be not working.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. Exception I was getting was not helpful.

Comment: @IvanStoev, works with `Int32(outerIt.CustomerId)`, thanks.

Comment: @shobhitvaish take a look for alternatives provided by Ivan, I think they are better (especially last one).

Comment: @Evk Lol :) There are different DynamicLINQ implementations (dialects), it's working in mine (`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`). Trial and error you know :) And `outerIt` is not supported, but `Contains(int(CustomerId))` works. Anyway, I think now OP has enough options, they can choose whatever works with the package they are using.

Comment: Saved me lot of time. Thanks.