# Implementing Dynamic LINQ Query with "NOT IN" Clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have dynamic string generated from back end which generates expression like:

```
"Col NOT IN ('ABC','CDE','EDF'...)"
```

I would like to make use of above string has predicate to my IEnumerable collection. Does Dynamic LINQ supports `NOT IN` operation?

Comment: I have assumed the  `ABC` `CDE` and `EDF` values are contained in a string array i.e. `notInArray = ["ABC", "CDE", "EDF"]`. Could you not simply do `collection = collection.Where(i => !notInArray.Contains(i.Col))`?

Comment: `IN` is `Contains` in LINQ: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15633066/861716

Comment: It's not supported directly (in fact Dynamic LINQ supports just a limited set of standard LINQ methods). You have to do parsing yourself. Or modify the backend to generate some more structured query definition instead of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this by using a SQL syntax that is much less common, but does the same thing:

```
"NOT (Col IN ('ABC','CDE','EDF'...))"
```

This works both for SQL and Dynamic Linq

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide your sample code but it seems something like;

```
var array = new [] {"ABD", "ABC", "BED"};
var result = _context.table.Where(x => !array.Any(y => x.Col1 == y));
```

Comment: `var result = _context.table.Where(x => !array.Contains(x.Col1));`

Comment: The question is about Dynamic LINQ.

Comment: I would like to implement in Dynamic LINQ not through LINQ. My String will be like "'ABC','DEF','GHI'".....comma separator with more than 15000 characters.